# Wildcard configured emails allow spammers to deliver mail? (SPF: "softfail")

Tags: email, g-suite, spf, dkim

I have a Google Apps account set up for one of my domains. Wildcard email delivery is enabled on this domain for all emails (ie. anything@domain.com passes emails along to myemail@domain.com), and the records related to email delivery are configured as follows (to the best of my knowledge, configured to Google's recommendations):

```
MX: ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM with priority 10
TXT: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
TXT: v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Recently, however, I have begun to receive an increased number of bounces/"out of office" emails from people who are apparently being spammed with people using email addresses from my domain. From the bounces, some headers:

```
Return-Path: <0379E403@domain.com>
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning 
    0379E403@domain.com does not designate 41.230.231.130
    as permitted sender) client-ip=41.230.231.130;
Authentication-Results: gmr-mx.google.com; spf=softfail (google.com:
    domain of transitioning 0379E403@domain.com does not designate
    41.230.231.130 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=0379E403@domain.com
From: "Secure.Message" <0379E403@domain.com>
To: <unfortunate_person@gmail.com>
```

(I can provide additional headers if needed.)

I looked into softfails but am not completely sure I understand it. I do wildcard emails to the domain so simply disabling wildcarding would probably not be a solution. Because emails to this domain are then forwarded on to a different email address (also within Google Apps, though), I would preferably also need to be able to send emails using Google's "send email as" ("on behalf of") feature.

Any ideas what to do now? Most importantly I am concerned about the reputation of my domain; I would very much want to keep it off of any spam lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `SoftFail` qualifier (the `~`) in an SPF mechanism, you indicate that a matching sender should be *treated with suspicion*, but not outright rejected.

The `Fail` qualifier (the `-`) on the other hand, encourages receiving MTAs to *reject the SMTP transfer immediately* with a 5.1.7 DSN.

So when you are using `~all` in the end of your record, you are only partially preventing spammers from abusing your domain and your reputation.

Read more about how check_host() results should be treated according to the RFC Specification here: [IETF RFC 4408](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt) §2.5 "Interpreting the results"

Comment: In other words, would it be recommended for me to change the qualifier to the "fail" qualifier?

Comment: I would definitely say so, yes!

Comment: It's interesting that Google makes no recommendation to use Fail as opposed to SoftFail in their documentation... do they not see this as a problem?

Comment: I think they keep the discussion within http://www.maawg.org/ in collaboration with other interest groups as opposed to having a "google-way" of doing things

Comment: I completely understand... it's the language that Google uses: "Publishing an SPF record that uses -all instead of ~all may result in delivery problems."

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Mathias said (which is good), note that key word *encourages* in his second sentense: "The Fail qualifier... encourages receiving MTAs to reject the email".

I would also recommend looking into [DMARC](http://dmarc.org/). Once you have SPF and DKIM records in place, which it sounds like you do, DMARC is a way for you to tell receiving mail servers what to do with email that fails *both* the SPF and DKIM test.

When an email fails those tests, AND a receiving MTA honors DMARC records, then you can control what they do with that email: Reject it outright, mark it as a spam, or deliver it.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the exact same situation, and changed my SPF records to perform a hard fail.  It doesn't help.  The administrators of the domains that send the bouncebacks seem to look at the spf record, see that it fails, and then ignore it.  I am not worried about my domain reputation, since they are going to continue to send these emails whether or not I am here to see the bouncebacks.  There is nothing you can do but make a rule to ignore the pattern of the reply to address.

Comment: ... Actually, there is. See my answer for how to implement DKIM and DMARC records. Not every mail server honors DMARC, but for the ones that do, this makes a big difference. I was successfully able to greatly reduce the amount of phishing emails our employees AND business points-of-contacts were receiving "from" our domain.

Comment: Thanks, I will definately look more into it.  I sign all my outgoing messages with DKIM, and I use SPF, of course.  I'm still reluctant to say that it will work, though. Researching some of the domains that I get bounce backs from leads me to believe that they will not honor DMARC.  Always looking to tighten up though.  I'll give it a go on my personal domain tonight.

Comment: I've implemented DMARC and configured it to drop emails that do not pass the test.  I set it up to request DMARC reports.  So far, I have not seen a reduction of the kind of emails described in the question. I received four DMARC reports so far, two each from Google and Yahoo.  I would recommend DMARC, but it is not helping in this particular situation.