# When creating DomainKeys does it matter if I use o=~ or o=-?

Tags: email, dkim, domainkeys

I used [this utility](http://www.unlocktheinbox.com/dkimwizard/) to create my DKIM key (1024 bit size), since Gmail has been blocking us (we had an old joomla install exploited, was around before me). And I got this back:

```
Your Selector Record:
default._domainkey.example.com IN TXT

"k=rsa;p=REALLYLONGSTRINGXXXXXXX"

Your Policy Record:
_domainkey.example.com IN TXT "o=~"
```

However, the DomainKey that MediaTemple's Plesk gave me had `o=-`,  so I used that for the policy record instead.

Is that OK?

I tested [with this](http://dkimcore.org/tools/) and also tried to test with some DKIM email testers, but have not gotten an email back from any of them.

Comment: FYI, 1024 bit keys are exploitable, and for that reason, Google recently upped their key strength to 2048 bit.  (And they're not alone.)  If you have the option, I would use a 2048 bit key, so you don't have to do this again anytime soon.

Comment: Google's guildelines at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126 haven't been updated with that information. My host wont let me put in more than 255 characters for a record

Answer (score 10):

The `o=` tag at the _domainkey root is mentioned in [this DKIM specification draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-allman-dkim-ssp-00) as an optional mechanism to indicate your outbound signing policy.

`o=~` means "some, but not all mails from this domain are signed"
`o=-` means "all mails from this domain are signed (though not necessarily by me)"

Much akin to (though not to be confused with) the [Fail and SoftFail qualifiers](https://serverfault.com/questions/466363/wildcard-configured-emails-allow-spammers-to-deliver-mail-spf-softfail/466375#466375) used in SPF.

Remember that **this is your signing policy**, *you* are the one to decide which policy indicator best meets your needs